# Ejb lookup failing when overriding getSingletons method from Application class

Tags: java, rest, dependency-injection, jax-rs, java-ee-6

I am trying to initialize my web service resources by myself overriding the getSingletons method from Application class. I am using Jboss EAP 6.0 app server. Below is the code

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private final Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public MyApplication() {
        singletons.add(new StudentFacade());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {

        return null; // Accidentally kept it as null but still my webservice was working. Dont know how it was working.
    }
}

@Path("student")
public class StudentFacade {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:global/ejb-beginner-sessions-ear/ejb-beginner-sessions-impl/StudentServiceBean!com.ejb.beginner.sessions.api.StudentService")
    private StudentService studentService;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(StudentFacade.class.getName());

    @GET
    @Path("list")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Student getStudents() {

        LOGGER.info("studentService: " + studentService);
        return new Student();
    }
}
```

Then I realized that getSingletons method is returning null and wondered how my webservice is still working.

I thought that because I am not returning the singletons, the application server is initializing the webservices by itself. So I removed @Resource and used @Inject and I got a WELD exception saying the dependency is not found.

Then I changed it to return the singletons and then @Resource did not lookup the ejb and studentService was null. So I used InitialContext to lookup the ejb and it worked.

```
try {
            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
            StudentService studentService = (StudentService) initialContext
                    .lookup("java:global/ejb-beginner-sessions-ear/ejb-beginner-sessions-impl/StudentServiceBean!com.ejb.beginner.sessions.api.StudentService");
            LOGGER.info("studentService1: " + studentService);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Can anyone please tell me

1. Why did the application server initialize the webservice despite I returned null
2. When I returned null, why @Inject failed and only @Resource was working.
3. When I returned singletons, why @Resource failed and only InitialContext was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "1. Why did the application server initialize the webservice despite I returned null"

When there are no classes/objects (or just empty sets) returned during lookup, the behavior will revert to classpath scanning for resources and providers (this is explained in the JAX-RS spec). Once *any* resource class or provider is returned from `getClasses` or `getSingleton`, it is assumed the developer handles the registration, and classpath registration is disabled.

> "2. When I returned null, why @Inject failed and only @Resource was working."

I don't see a success case in any of your arguments for `@Inject`, so I will not try to make a comment on that. As for `@Resource`, it seems to be the correct way to inject your resource. When classpath registration is enabled, you don't create the JAX-RS class, the runtime does. The runtime also handles the injection. If you create the instance yourself, the runtime will not try to inject.

> "3. When I returned singletons, why @Resource failed and only InitialContext was working."

This is partly answered above. When you instantiate the class, injection is not performed. When the runtime creates the instances, it goes through the injection process.

---

One thing to note is that when you instantiate, the resource class will be a singleton, meaning only one instance per application. This may or may not be the desired behavior. When the runtime instantiates the class, by default it will be in request scoped, meaning one instance created per request. Again, may or may not be what you want. If you want to maintain the classpath registration, and still be singleton, then annotation the resource class with `@javax.inject.Singleton` should make it a singleton, and still allow injection, as the runtime still instantiates the class. If you want the classes to be request scoped, and want to register all your classes yourself, the override `public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()` and add your classes to the set.

Comment: I just discovered that my ejb is annotated with `@Remote` and that is why `@Inject` failed.